# Extract x and y values from periodogram

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, spectrum

Is there a way to extract the x and y values of a periodogram as a data frame in R? I would like to extract the corresponding values of y and plot it using ggplot

library(TSA)

Periodogram(data)

[image: Periodogram]

Comment: If you do `p <- periodogram(data)` then `p$freq` and `p$spec` give you the values you want.

Comment: Oh thanks. that worked